# Pacote nuget no IIS local ou numa intra

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis, nuget

Configurei o `nuget` local e funcionou muito bem, tanto na minha máquina como na rede. O que eu quero é colocar os pacotes(`DLL`) no `IIS`, de forma que, ao passar o endereço(`URL`) de onde está as `DLL's`, possamos instalar. Optamos pelo `IIS`, que é mais fácil restringir o acesso desautorizado do que controlar pasta na rede. O que passa é que não sei como fazer. Fiz os passos, parecido com a instalação local, mas apontando para o `IIS`. Isso não deu certo. Não dá erro nenhum, mas não acha nada, fica o tempo todo a barra de progresso "pesquisando" e nada. Como eu faço isso? Alguém sabe? No aguardo.

Comment: Cara, na própria documentação da nuget tem ensinando como fazer http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

Answer (score 0):

na empresa em que trabalho criamos um portal para publicar nossos pacotes nuget, utilizamos a biblioteca NuGet.Server (disponível como nuget). Segue um link com maiores detalhes: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx